# How to get a vector type from a FloatVectorProperty?

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics

How do I get the `mathutils.Vector` from the `FloatVectorProperty` in a python script? Sometimes it works other times I get a type mismatch:

```
import bpy
import mathutils

prop_vector = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(default=(1,2,3))
print(prop_vector)

util_vector = mathutils.Vector([1,2,3])
print(util_vector)

prop_vector + util_vector
```

This gives me this output:

[image]

**Q:** How do I get a vector type from that property?

Comment: Set the subtype of a `FloatVectorProperty` to eg. `Direction` in order to get a vector: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty

Comment: I've tried several subtypes and my prop_vector is still a two component tuble. I think I read somewhere that I could write list(prop_vector) or something, but this didn't work for me either.

Comment: I think @batFINGER did a good job explaining it... added the test for my comment to his post. Another good reason why providing your code is necessary ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Incorrect usage.**

> [**Property Definitions (bpy.props)**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#module-bpy.props)
>
> This module defines properties to extend Blender’s internal data. The
> result of these functions is used to assign properties to classes
> registered with Blender **and can’t be used directly**.

In python can set up a property on some class `Foo` with

```
Foo.prop = property(getter, setter)
```

the property definitions module is doing much the same for blender classes, with added goodies for UI etc.

```
>>> bpy.types.Scene.prop_vector = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(default=(1,2,3))
>>> C.scene.prop_vector[:]
(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Notice it is a tuple the size of the vector property (default 3).  To make it of vector type

```
v = Vector(C.scene.prop_vector)
```

---

Also consider to set the [`subtype`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty) of the [`FloatVectorProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty) to eg. `Direction` to get `<class 'Vector'>` out of the box.  DIRECTION will typecast it to a vector but assign it no units.  For a translation use 'TRANSLATION` to put the lengths in chosen scene units (eg millimeters, inches).  *See also the unit property*

Generic XYZ vector

```
>>> bpy.types.Scene.foo = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(subtype='XYZ')
>>> C.scene.foo
Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Following demo is based on `operator_simple.py` template:

```
import bpy
import mathutils
    
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Print type to console
        print (type(context.scene.my_vector))
        # Vector addition demo
        print(context.scene.my_vector + mathutils.Vector((1, 2, 3)))
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_vector = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
            default=(1, 1, 1), 
            subtype='DIRECTION')

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Comment: Aah. I think I get it now. I completely misunderstood what properties are. Thanks a lot! So if I want a sort of global variable I can add a FloatVectorProperty to bpy.types.scene, which I can then access acces via  bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].Vector (although this is actually an array)

Comment: Or in an operator I can use context.scene.my_vector. This really helped me a lot!

Comment: or workspace.  Use window_manager for session globals.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll keep that in mind